# Убрать тень ActionBar

Tags: android

Как убрать тень у ActionBar? Пытаюсь так убрать не работает

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: какая версия андрюши? в каком месте это применяете? покажите разметку ...

Comment: Версия андроид 6 и 7, пишу этот код в MainActivity тут   

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

Comment: а toolbar  не в AppBarLayout случаем?

Comment: да, в AppBarLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете AppBarLayout, то установите `app:elevation="0dp"` в `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`, и тогда все заработает.

Comment: заработало. Спасибо

Comment: @Кокосовый пожалуйста, обращайтесь. Только в следующий раз постарайтесь более полно описывать проблему =)

Comment: Учту. Спасибо :)